# Confused on git workflow (PHP/MySQL)

Tags: git, workflow

I have a question regarding the proper workflow of git in a PHP/MySQL workflow.  The git repository has a config file with "blank" database data, just like any PHP/MySQL application.  MY question is related to development (pulling/cloning) -> development stage -> production (push).

So, I want to be able to clone my repository (blank MySQL config file), do some development (this is where I'd edit the "blank" config file) on my dev instance which includes testing,  and then push back to the repository (with a blank MySQL file, instead of with password information).

This might be super easy, I just do not have the knowledge of how git could do such a thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create another file with the same name as your current config file and add something like .sample or .dist to the end of it. i.e on my system i personally have my settings in config.php which is ignored by git and will never upload to the site, and i also have a config.php.dist (like distribution) which will push up to the repo.

So when your client downloads it, they just need to rename config.php.dist and remove the .dist part.

Second thing to do, you need to create a .gitignore in the root of the repo folder, and add the file name that you do not want to upload to the repo.

Contents of .gitignore
config.php.dist

Comment: This sounds very suitable for me, so this should work - thanks :)